# How to change the color of correct answer using JavaScript when check answer button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
  <span class="correct">(B)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
  <span class="correct">(A)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
  <span class="correct">(D) Lorem ipsum dolor</span></p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>
```

how to change the color of the correct option when 'check answer' button of the question clicked?

Comment: So, where's your javascript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the hard coded `correct` class on each span element and define the class in css, then on button click find the corresponding span(answer) element and add the class to the element:

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('ans-button')].forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', highlightAnswer));

function highlightAnswer() {
    const answer = event.target.previousElementSibling.querySelector('span');
    answer.classList.add('correct');
}
```

```css
.correct {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
  <span>(B)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor
</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
  <span>(A)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor
</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br><span>(D) Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery, it's pretty easy:

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
  <span class="correct">(B)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br>
  <span class="correct">(A)Lorem ipsum dolor</span><br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (D) Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit<br> (A)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (B)Lorem ipsum dolor<br> (C) Lorem ipsum dolor<br>
  <span class="correct">(D) Lorem ipsum dolor</span></p>
<button class="ans-button">check answer</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var a = $(".ans-button").on("click", function() {
    $(this).prev().find(".correct").css("color", "green");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the IF ELSE  here, if answer is correct, you make .class in css giving it color, if answer is correct, CSS applies, if not, it goes to else, which can be left empty not applying anything or you can give alert if you want as bonus telling its wrong or giving it other color